# wcf service getting access denied using dllimport on deployment

Tags: wcf

I am using a simple wcf service. It works on localhost but when I deploy it to winhost, a shared hosting, I get this error:

The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Access is denied.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at ....

It actually works fine if I remove a DLLimport function that I use. I am not sure if this is a permission issue or some other errors. My dll is in my bin folder.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I use a sort of reflector tool to read the source code, I think the exception is caused by code access security. I think following link can help you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700337.aspx

You may increase the server permission level to allow the DllImport method.

Comment: I took a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500644.aspx and I tried using                                 [assembly:AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers] and [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Assert,Name = "FullTrust")] but it still gave me the same errors.